# Why JS addEventListener is not working in this code?

Tags: javascript, css, addeventlistener

I've this code and it's not working. I know it would be some obvious typo or logical error but I am not able to find it. When I click at any `nav-item`, it doesn't change the background of body. I'm new to JS. Please help me with this -

```js
let body = document.querySelector("body");
let navBack = document.getElementById("navbar");
let introNav = document.querySelector(".nav-item1");
let expNav = document.querySelector(".nav-item2");
let projectsNav = document.querySelector(".nav-item3");
let skillsNav = document.querySelector(".nav-item4");
let contactNav = document.querySelector(".nav-item5");

introNav.addEventListener("click", function() {
  body.style.background = introNav.style.background;
  navBack.style.background = introNav.style.background
})

expNav.addEventListener("click", function() {
  body.style.background = expNav.style.background;
  navBack.style.background = expNav.style.background
})

projectsNav.addEventListener("click", function() {
  body.style.background = projectsNav.style.background;
  navBack.style.background = projectsNav.style.background
})

skillsNav.addEventListener("click", function() {
  body.style.background = skillsNav.style.background;
  navBack.style.background = skillsNav.style.background
})

contactNav.addEventListener("click", function() {
  body.style.background = contactNav.style.background;
  navBack.style.background = contactNav.style.background
})
```

```css
#navbar {
    background: var(--introduction-color);
    z-index: 1;
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    top: -400px;
    left: -400px;
}
.nav-items {
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    cursor: pointer;
    clip-path: polygon(50% 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 66%);
}
.nav-item1 {
    background: var(--introduction-color);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.nav-item2 {
    transform: rotate(63deg);
    background: var(--experience-color);
}
.nav-item3 {
    transform: rotate(81deg);
    background: var(--projects-color);
}
.nav-item4 {
    transform: rotate(99deg);
    background: var(--skills-color);
}
.nav-item5 {
    transform: rotate(117deg);
    background: var(--contacts-color);
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <div class="nav-items nav-item1"></div>
  <div class="nav-items nav-item2"></div>
  <div class="nav-items nav-item3"></div>
  <div class="nav-items nav-item4"></div>
  <div class="nav-items nav-item5"></div>
</div>
```

Image - [Image of the navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vFGw.png)

Comment: `.style` gives you the inline styles of an element (that you add with `style=""` attribute on the element itself). Trying to access the styles like you're currently tring to do won't work. One option is to use `getComputedStyle` or look into using classes to drive your backgrounds and then add that class to `body`/`navBack`

Comment: It's working when I assign some value to the element in JS file like `introNav.style.background = "blue"` then by clicking this `introNav` element, body background color changes to blue. I don't understand. I can assign css colors to every element one by one then it will work but will it be ideal to type 20 extra lines or should I look for other logical solutions ? (I haven't searched about this `getComputedStyle` property yet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element.style` can only access **inline** styles (those assigned via a `style="..."` attribute):

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('.item')
  .forEach(
    item => console.log(item, 'style.color:', item.style.color)
  );
```

```html
<div class="item">Test</div>
<div class="item" style="color: red;">With inline style</div>
```

To access the currently applied value of color, you'll have to resort to `window.getComputedStyle(element)`:

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('.item')
  .forEach(
    item => console.log(item, getComputedStyle(item).color)
  );
```

```html
<div class="item">Test</div>
<div class="item" style="color: red;">With inline style</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man. Saved me from quitting this project. It's working that way.

Answer (score -1):

put the script at the bottom of the page or use const introNav = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-item1");

Comment: Yes, the script is at the bottom and tried this `const introNav = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-item1")` still not working.

Comment: Is it hosted somewhere and I console and debug ?

Comment: No, it's local for now and the code is pretty much that's it.

Comment: Please check here https://devforhelp.com/code.html

Comment: I have added static colors because variable was not defined and you can change the css back again.

Comment: Thanks for the help man. It's just like I wanted it to be. Now I can continue work on this. Thanks!